# Passing the button label to a string in another activity

Tags: ios, swift

My code runs without any errors but it doesn't pass the label of the button to the next activity

here is the code

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var Properties: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var games: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var electronics: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var Vehicles: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var Accessories: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var searchTitle: UISearchBar?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        var pass:searchResultView = segue.destinationViewController as! searchResultView
        if(electronics.selected){
            if(searchTitle?.text != nil){
                pass.tit = searchTitle?.text
            }
        pass.received = electronics.titleLabel!.text!
        }
        else if(games.selected){
            if(searchTitle?.text != nil){
                pass.tit = searchTitle?.text
            }
            pass.received = games.titleLabel!.text!
        }
        else if(Properties.selected){
            if(searchTitle?.text != nil){
                pass.tit = searchTitle?.text
            }
            pass.received = Properties.titleLabel!.text!
        }
        else if(Vehicles.selected){
            if(searchTitle?.text != nil){
                pass.tit = searchTitle?.text
            }
            pass.received = Vehicles.titleLabel!.text!
        }
        else if(Accessories.selected){
            if(searchTitle?.text != nil){
                pass.tit = searchTitle?.text
            }
            pass.received = Accessories.titleLabel!.text!
        }
    }
```

when i try to println the string in the other activity, it prints nothing

here is the code of the other activity

```
class searchResultView: UIViewController {

    var received:String = ""
    var tit:String? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        println(received)
        println(tit)

        println("jsoidjf")
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

please can any one help me, am lost!

Comment: Are you test it pass it only the variables without checking any condition to see if the variables are passed?

Comment: @VictorSigler yes i tested it, they're not passed, i don't know where is the problem in the code, am new to swift

Comment: What do you actually see in the console when you run this?  Does it successfully print something as the "received" variable, and does it successfully print "jsoidjf"?  Or do those not get printed, either?

Comment: Have you create it your segue in code or using Storyboard?

Comment: Another thing, you are sure you're entering in the `prepareForSegue`? Your issue is very uncommon, I tested it right now with the same variables and everything works fine.

Comment: @cc. it successfully prints "jsoidjf", but the other strings am passing doesnt print, for the tit, it prints nil

Comment: @VictorSigler using segue

Comment: @VictorSigler it works fine with me, but the label inside the button is not passed to received,, does it with u? if yes, can you show me ur code?

Comment: have you checked that any of the if conditions for the buttons have actually been triggered? i don´t know if checking for the `selected` is actually a wise idea!?

Comment: Yes it is passed fine to the `received` variable without any problem? Can you share your project in Github or something else to check out?

Comment: Where you are setting the selected property of UIButton? In interface builder or in code.?

Comment: @luk2302 are there any other way of doing it? can u please tell if there is

Comment: @VictorSigler here https://www.dropbox.com/s/d25hvogr8mz8ms2/barakah.zip?dl=0

Comment: @VictorSigler please check my code and tell me where is the problem, if u couldn't find it, share with me ur code which working

Comment: From your code i can see you did not enabled the button. And default value of selected is false. So it is not going inside the if block.

Comment: @Amit89 how should i solve? can u please guide me through the solution

Comment: are you triggering the segues via code like `performSegueWithIdentifier` or are you connecting the button actions via Interface builder to some other view as segue?

Comment: @luk2302 the only methode am using for segues is prepareForSegue, am new to swift only 3 days programming with it, not sure of what ur point

Comment: @luk2302 u can check my code, i posted a dropbox link u can download it

Comment: checked the dropbox and solved it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options

## 1. Setting identifiers for the segues

You need to set an identifier of your segues in the Interface Builder to detect which one is getting triggered:

- click the segue you want to set the identifier for
- on the left you will get the button highlighted the segues originates from
- on the right choose the `Attributes Inspector` and type in an identifer

[image]

Then change your code accordingly to something like:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var pass:searchResultView = segue.destinationViewController as! searchResultView
    if (segue.identifier == "electronicsSegue") { 
    /* choose the same identifier as in the attribute inspector */
        if(searchTitle?.text != nil){
            pass.tit = searchTitle?.text
        }
        pass.received = electronics.titleLabel!.text!
    }
}
```

## 2. Checking the sender object

This version is easier to perform but not as clean, check if the sender of a triggered segue is equal to one of your buttons:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var pass:searchResultView = segue.destinationViewController as! searchResultView
    let senderButton = sender as! UIButton

    if(senderButton == electronics){
        if(searchTitle?.text != nil){
            pass.tit = searchTitle?.text
        }
        pass.received = electronics.titleLabel!.text!
    }
}
```

Both solutions output

> Electronics
>
> Optional("")
>
> jsoidjf

Answer (score 0):

Add this method and try. Create `@IBAction` method

```
@IBAction func electronicsAction(sender: UIButton) {

  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("PushToSearchViewController", sender: self)
  self.electronics.selected = true
}
```

First provide identifier to the segue, i am doing here only for electronics button.